# Как передать API в Presenner от Moxy используя Dagger 2 2.10+

Tags: android, dagger2, moxy

Добрый день.

Столкнулся с проблемой при переходе на Dagger2 версии 2.11 и выше вместе с Moxy. 
У меня есть презентер от Мокси, в который нужно передать API. Заинжектить это Api туда нет возможности, т.к. в Даггере, начиная с версии 2.10, использовать метод  `AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this);` для получения зависимостей могут только Activity/Fragment. Следовательно, этот Api нужно передавать в презетер через его конструктор. Проблема в том, что данный презентер не имеет конструктора во фрагменте, т.к. сам инжектится следующим образом:

```
  @InjectPresenter(type = PresenterType.WEAK)
    public WeatherPresenter weatherPresenter;
```

Благо у Moxy есть возможность добавить аннотацию   `@ProvidePresenter` и добавить входные параметры:

```
@Inject
@ProvidePresenter(type = PresenterType.WEAK)
WeatherPresenter provideWeatherPresenter(WeatherApi weatherApi) {
    return new WeatherPresenter(weatherApi);
}
```

Однако, тут появляется другая проблема, судя по всему, Dagger не распознает вышеописанный кусок кода, поэтому выдается вот такая вот ошибка:

> Error:(24, 20) error: method provideWeatherPresenter in class
>   BaseFragment cannot be applied to given types; required: WeatherApi
>   found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in
>   length

Подскажите, может кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой? Есть ли возможность как-то "прокинуть" Api в презентер используя пару Moxy+Dagger 2.10+ или же пользоваться Даггером по старому

Comment: По идее вам надо создавать экземпляр презентера не во фрагменте/активити, но в  `@Provides` методе одного из модулей `dagger`.  После этого вы сможете инжектить презентер через `@Inject Provider<PresenterClassName> provider`, а из метода с аннотацией `@ProvidePresenter` возвращать `provider.get()`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я решил проблему через Moxy, метод с аннотацией `@ProvidePresenter` не принимает параметров, но в самом модуле можно использовать  ранее "заинжектенный" API